# How to get the validation message in laravel-validation-rules/credit-card

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-blade, credit-card

I used the laravel validator for credit card information as per instructed [here](https://github.com/laravel-validation-rules/credit-card).
I can finally let it work but my problem is how can I make its result readable by a user. I am also using Laravel validation like this:

```
public static function validate()
{
    $val = [
           'card_num' => ['required', 'numeric', new CardNumber],
    ];

    return $val;
}
```

So, if I clicked the submit button and the field is empty, the result is `card numは必須です。` which means card number is required. And if I supply an invalid card number, the result is `validation.credit_card.card_length_invalid`, how can I make it has the same result as leaving the field empty? I do like this when getting the validation errors in blade php.

```
<div>
    <label>カード番号</label>
    <input type="text" name="card_num" id="credit-card" value="{{ old('card_num', $user['card_num']) }}" >
</div>
@if ($errors->has('card_num'))
<p class="alert-error">
    {{ $errors->first('card_num') }}
</p>
@endif
```

**UPDATE**

I have seen its source file and messages, but I don't want to directly change the vendor files.
I have tried adding the `custom` in `validation.php`, but it's not working.

```
'custom' => [
    'validation.card_length_invalid' => '無効なカード長',
    'validation.credit_card' => 'クレジットカード',
],
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your array in `validation.php` is close to correct. Try changing the top-level key to `credit_card` instead of `custom` like they have in the [source code](https://github.com/laravel-validation-rules/credit-card/blob/master/src/CardNumber.php#L12). I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think this package supports messages in the `custom` array like the ordinary Laravel rules do. For example:

```
'credit_card' => [
   'card_length_invalid' => '無効なカード長',
   'credit_card' => 'クレジットカード',
],
```